# AngularJS - ng-class with value from ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set the class of a tr using ng-class with the value of ng-repeat. All the examples I see online seem to call a function. Can i just set the ng-class with a value rather than using a function?

None of these work.

```
<tr ng-class="{{res.resopnse.label}}" ng-repeat="res in responses">
<tr ng-class="res.resopnse.label" ng-repeat="res in responses">
<tr ng-class="{res.resopnse.label}" ng-repeat="res in responses">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no conditional logic, you can just interpolate into `class` attribute directly:

```
<tr class="{{res.resopnse.label}}" ng-repeat="res in responses">
```