# Cell specific table styling with ng-class and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-class

I am trying to apply cell-level styling to a table with ng-reapt and ng-class.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="transaction in transactionsArr" class="no-top-border">
        <td ng-class="{{transaction.cellstyle}}">{{transaction.Reason}}</td>
        <td class="align-right">{{transaction.account}}</td>
        <td class="align-right">{{transaction.Amount| number:0}}</td>
        <td class="align-right">{{transaction.Balance| number:0}}</td>
    </tr>
```

However I am getting errors with this.
I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126193/angularjs-ng-class-with-value-from-ng-repeat) question but it is not working.

Is this not possible to apply specific styling each entry with ng-repeat?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use interpolation. `ng-class="transaction.cellstyle"`

Comment: you either need `class="{{transaction.cellstyle}}"` or `ng-class="transaction.cellstyle"`, `ng-class` is recommended

Comment: Lex, Aleksey, thank you! It worked.